# Arduino Error: expected unqualified-id before '['

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and I get the following Error:

> Simple_Display_Text_From_Android:6:5: error: expected unqualified-id
> before '[' token  char[] IncomingText = {}; // for processing and
> printing incoming text to arudino
> ^ C:\Users\Muaz Aljarhi\Documents\Arduino\Simple_Display_Text_From_Android\Simple_Display_Text_From_Android.ino:
> In function 'void loop()': Simple_Display_Text_From_Android:16:3:
> error: 'IncomingText' was not declared in this scope    IncomingText =
> Serial.read();      //Read the incoming data and store it into
> variable IncomingText    ^ exit status 1 expected unqualified-id
> before '[' token

Here is the code:

```
char[] IncomingText = {}; // for processing and printing incoming text to arudino
    
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600); //Sets the data rate in bits per second (baud) for serial data transmission
    
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      IncomingText = Serial.read();      //Read the incoming data and store it into variable IncomingText
      Serial.print(IncomingText);        //Print Value of IncomingText in Serial monitor
      Serial.print("\n");        //New line 
    }
```

How to fix?

Comment: Assuming this is C or C++ it would have to be `char IncomingText[]` instead. Though that won't solve all your issues, as your `loop` is also incorrect on the reading part

Comment: Yes so how to convert read text to string or char array?

Comment: There's a `readString` function: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change  the brackets  try this code

```html
char[] IncomingText = [] ; // for processing and printing incoming text to arudino
    
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600); //Sets the data rate in bits per second (baud) for serial data transmission
    
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      IncomingText = Serial.read();      //Read the incoming data and store it into variable IncomingText
      Serial.print(IncomingText);        //Print Value of IncomingText in Serial monitor
      Serial.print("\n");        //New line 
    }
```